# Hibernate not Mapping correctly

Tags: hibernate, kubernetes, playframework

## Context:

I am currently trying to setup a connection between my **database** and my **application**, running on **k8s**, all running on **DigitalOcean**. My database is accepting all incoming connections for testing purposes right now. That enables me to let my application run locally but still connect to my remote database via **Hibernate**. The database is called "User" like the entity. Not "users" or "Users", I am not using annotations for tables or entities as in the problems I found.

## Problem:

Running locally is no problem at all - it runs queries without any problem. But when my k8s pod application tries to run queries, the following error comes up:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [SELECT c from User c WHERE c.email = :email]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:622)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:734)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:77)
```

It is not limited to the entity "User" its all tables of course. This is just an example because it is the first query in the login use-case.

## A little snippet from my User class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "system-uuid")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String organizationID;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private boolean isActivated;
    ...
```

## My question:

Why does it work locally and not in my pod? To me, it does not seem to have anything to do with the connection, or am I incorrect?

Thanks in advance, I hope to get an answer soon.

Kind regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you are packaging/deploying your application, but the error means that the entity class is not known to Hibernate. Could be that you are missing a persistence.xml. Maybe the resulting JAR/WAR file that you deploy doesn't contain the entity class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer first of all!
I am deploying my application with Docker. The Image is built using a plugin for sbt. I do have a persistence.xml, but no hibernate config because I read that annotations should already do the job.

Comment: Take a look into the JAR of the image. Maybe something is missing? Also, it's important that you know how your application is started up. Do you use Spring? Because Spring does annotation scanning and configures Hibernate. If you just run your application through a custom main method, chances are that however you package you application up makes it impossible for Hibernate to find the appropriate entity classes.

Comment: Thank you again! I am using the Play Framework and unfortunately it seems like guice injection is only working partially. I mean, the persistence.xml is not overriden, only locally. When the app is deployed the persistence.xml is the source of truth which I find really odd since it's said that it shouldn't be like that. Anyway, that's how I got it working now. I am thinking about making a tutorial in case someone has the same problem though it seems Play is not used very often. Thanks for your help!